# AWS EC2 restored volume from snapshot updates java version on boot

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot

I have an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux) running a very old version of java (legacy software).

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.6.4.0.65.amzn1-x86_64 u95-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

When I snapshot the boot volume of this instance, and then create a new volume from the snapshot, attach it as the boot volume of another instance, boot up the new instance, then check the java version, this is what I see:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_211"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.6.17.1.79.amzn1-x86_64 u211-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.211-b02, mixed mode)
```

I don't understand why the java version changes when the instance boots. I have verified that this only happens when the volume boots up in an instance. Attaching it as a secondary volume to a running instance first, shows the correct (older) version.

Attached as a secondary drive:

```
$ ls -l /media/new_vol/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5456 Feb  2  2016 /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
```

Once booted up as the boot volume of an instance:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5464 Mar 13 17:50 /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
```

Anyone seen this before? Any ideas why this is happening? Both the old instance and the new instance are running the same generation and class of instance type.

Comment: Does this mean you do _not_ want it to update? You could try an experiment where you do not give it a public IP address until after it has booted (wait several minutes). You can then give it a public IP address and login to check the java version. This method should avoid any auto-updates that are running when the instance boots.

Comment: That's correct, I don't want it to update. The instance is in a private subnet with NATted access to the Internet. But I see your point, I'll try by blocking it's Internet access. Interesting thing is that the old instance (snapshot source) never updated, despite numerous restarts.

Comment: Ah! Check the User Data. It only runs _once per Instance ID_. So, if the original instance boots, it won't run. But if the disk is copied/placed on a new instance (which will have a different Instance ID), then the User Data will run again.

Comment: So when I booted the instance without Internet access, it did not update. So far so good. Now the question is how to block it from updating? I checked the User Data (right click instance in the AWS console, Instance Settings, Change/View User Data) and it's blank. Is there any place in the OS where I can control /stop the update process?

Comment: Perhaps this should resolve the issue? According to https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/, to disable the security update on boot, modify /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg and change repo_upgrade: security to repo_upgrade: none.